# Are the greatest poet among the painters and the greatest painter among the poets the same person?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, applications

I have come across this question (based on set theory) in my textbook and I've tried solving it twice but alas, could anybody help me out with it?

*Are the greatest painter among the poets and the greatest poet among the painters the same person?*

And, quite a similar one,

*Are the oldest painter among the poets and the oldest poet among the painters the same person?*

For the first one, I suppose that there is a chance that they can't be the same person but failed to come up with a concrete proof with or without a Venn diagram.

Could anybody help me out with it?

*For reference, the question is from Sydsaeter, Hammond's Mathematics for Economic Analysis tenth edition*

Comment: I suggest:  write out examples with a small number of each type.  Keep in mind that a single counterexample is all you need to show that the general claim is false.

Comment: A well explained Venn diagram is a correct proof.

Comment: The first condition is equivalent to the condition that the greatest painter is also the greatest poet. The second one compares the oldest painter also being a poet with the oldest poet also being a painter , in other words , the oldest person being both a poet and a painter. Hence the second condition is always satisfied as soon as there is a person being both a poet and a painter.

Comment: "Greatness" means different things in the different communities.  To be the "greatest painter" would under most interpretations mean something along the lines that they created *a painting* which is more highly rated than other paintings.  Similarly, being the "greatest poet" would require having made *a poem* that is highly regarded compared to others.  Consider a scenario with only two people to consider.  Both are poets and painters.  The first made an amazing painting and a terrible poem.  The second made an amazing poem and a terrible painting.

Comment: In comparison... "*oldest*" means the same thing in both communities.

Comment: @Peter the first condition is equivalent to the condition that the greatest painter *among specifically only those people who are both painters and poets* is also the greatest poet *among specifically only those people who are both painters and poets*, which may or may not be the greatest painter among painters and may or may not be the greatest poet among poets.  I don't find this rewording to be sufficiently different than the original statement to have warranted mention, but your wording was incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first. Perhaps some painters aren't poets and some poets aren't painters. We simply don't know.

Let $A$ be the set of all painters ***and*** poets, that is the intersection of the two sets of poets and painters.

We will construct $A$ in such a manner: $A$ consists of pairs of the form $(x,y)$ where $x$ denotes the person's skill in painting and $y$ in poetry. We rated them all from a theoretical scale of $0$ to $100$ (meaning not all values are necessarily occuring), thus $A=\{(x,y)| x,y\in (0,1,\dots,100)\}$.

Let's say that the greatest score on painting skills was $98$ , thus $x=98$. Similarly let's assume that the greatest score on poetry skills was $91$ , thus $y=91$.

There is no reason to assume that these values refer *to the same person*. That is, we might have $a_1=(98, 73)$ be the greatest painter amongst poets and $a_2=(43, 91)$ the greatest poet amongst painters with $a_1\neq a_2$.

So we have constructed an example where the greatest painter amongst poets and the greatest poet amongst painters are different persons.

It's easy to see that this condition holds for our example: $\forall a_i \in A, 0\le x\le98 $ **and** $0\le y\le91$

Then again, it might very well be that if $\max x = \max y$ $\forall a_i \in A$, then indeed the greatest painter among the poets and the greatest poet among the painters is the same person but ***it is not necessarily so***.